# Owl Carousel Outer Arrow Navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, carousel, owl-carousel

I'm trying to implement the Owl Carousel with Lazyload images for a portfolio site and am having issues with positioning my navigation buttons. Ideally i'd like to add these on the outside of the carousel positioned halfway up the image. I have seen a couple of examples where this is operational but just cannot fathom it out. Can someone please help?

I have added a JSfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/iameuanmackay/448htq9b/

The code i'm using is:

```
<div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-push-2 col-md-push-3 col-lg-6 col-lg-push-3" style="padding-left:45px">
    <div class="owl-demo">
        <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="http://megmackayphoto.com/Beta/lib/img/full/people_02.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="http://megmackayphoto.com/Beta/lib/img/full/people_02.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="http://megmackayphoto.com/Beta/lib/img/full/people_03.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="http://megmackayphoto.com/Beta/lib/img/full/people_04.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="owl-lazy" data-src="http://megmackayphoto.com/Beta/lib/img/full/people_05.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#owl-demo .item {
  display: block;
  padding: 30px 0px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: #FFF;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}
.owl-theme .owl-controls {
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
/* Styling Next and Prev buttons */
.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-buttons div {
  color: #FFF;
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
  /*IE7 life-saver */
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background: #869791;
  filter: Alpha(Opacity=50);
  /*IE7 fix*/
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

And the `js` is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('.owl-demo').owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    nav: true,
    navigationText: [
        "<i class='icon-chevron-left icon-white'><</i>",
        "<i class='icon-chevron-right icon-white'>></i>"],
    lazyLoad: true,
    loop: true,
    margin: 10
  });
});
```

Any guidance that can be given on what i'm doing wrong would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".slider1").owlCarousel({
    margin: 15,
    items:1,
    responsiveClass:true,
    nav: true,
    autoHeight: true,
    loop:false,
    navText: [
      "<i class='fa fa-chevron-left'></i>",
      "<i class='fa fa-chevron-right'></i>"
    ],
    loop:true,
    responsiveClass:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        }
    }
  }); 
});
```

```css
@import url(http://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css);
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css);
@import url(http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css);

.owl-carousel {
 margin: 0;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-nav [class*=owl-] {
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
 font-size: 11px;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 line-height: 30px;
 border-radius: 0;
 text-align: center;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-nav [class*=owl-]:hover {
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
 color: #FFF;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-prev,
.owl-carousel .owl-next {
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px;
 height: 30px;
 margin: auto !important;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-prev {
 right: 45px;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-next {
 right: 10px;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-dots {
 display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Owl Carousel - Single Slider</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="owl-carousel slider1">
          <figure>
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RGGxODF.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="...">
          </figure>
          <figure>
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RGGxODF.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="...">
          </figure>
          <figure>
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RGGxODF.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="...">
          </figure>
          <figure>
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RGGxODF.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="...">
          </figure>
          <figure>
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RGGxODF.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="...">
          </figure>  
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I suggest you to improve your example by reading the [Minimal, Complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: for old version just use `.owl-theme .owl-controls`

Answer (score 11):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var carousel = $("#owl-demo");
    carousel.owlCarousel({
      navigation:true,
      navigationText: [
        "<i class='icon-chevron-left icon-white'><</i>",
        "<i class='icon-chevron-right icon-white'>></i>"
      ],
  });          
});
```

Demo link:  http://codepen.io/OwlFonk/pen/qhgjb/

Comment: for owl-carousel-2 change `navigationText` to `navText`

Comment: also change `navigation` to `nav`

Answer (score 0):

navigationText: ["", ""]

full code is below:

```
var owl1 = $("#main-demo");
owl1.owlCarousel({
    navigation: true, // Show next and prev buttons
    slideSpeed: 300,
    pagination:false,
    singleItem: true, transitionStyle: "fade",
    navigationText: ["", ""]
});// Custom Navigation Events

owl1.trigger('owl.play', 4500);
```